# How to get values from a particular ID using JSON in CardView in Android

Tags: android, json

I want to develop an Android app using recyclerview CardView, getting data from JSON file.

The error I am facing is I'm getting the images and text for all users, rather than just a particular user's data, in a particular post (like Facebook).

Here is my JSON code:

```
{
    "posts": [{
        "post_id": "59",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "karan",
        "lastname": "qq",
        "created_at": "2017-05-30 23:17:46",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1496166466_IMG-20170529-WA0041.jpg",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "58",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0a",
        "firstname": "karan",
        "lastname": "qq",
        "created_at": "2017-05-30 12:12:36",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "57",
        "post_desc": "Good Morning",
        "firstname": "karan",
        "lastname": "qq",
        "created_at": "2017-05-30 11:29:43",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "56",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-26 16:50:49",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "55",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "jaxi",
        "lastname": "chawda",
        "created_at": "2017-05-26 16:50:04",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "54",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-26 16:47:24",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1495797444_IMG_20170522_191006_842.jpg",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "53",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-26 16:45:18",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "52",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "jaxi",
        "lastname": "chawda",
        "created_at": "2017-05-26 16:32:24",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "51",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-26 16:18:31",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "50",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "karan",
        "lastname": "qq",
        "created_at": "2017-05-23 17:37:19",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1495541239_VID-20170518-WA0029.mp4",
            "file_type": "2"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "49",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-16 16:19:13",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494931753_IMG_3919.mp4",
            "file_type": "2"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "48",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "jaxi",
        "lastname": "chawda",
        "created_at": "2017-05-16 15:09:32",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494927572_Technology in the Future.mp4",
            "file_type": "2"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "47",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "pankti",
        "lastname": "shah",
        "created_at": "2017-05-16 13:30:09",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494921609_Tom and Jerry - Little School Mouse.mp4",
            "file_type": "2"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "46",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "pankti",
        "lastname": "shah",
        "created_at": "2017-05-16 13:16:34",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494920794_Tubelight _ Official Teaser _ Salman Khan _ Kabir Khan.mp4",
            "file_type": "2"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "45",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "pankti",
        "lastname": "shah",
        "created_at": "2017-05-16 13:13:51",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494920631_small.mp4",
            "file_type": "2"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "44",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-13 16:45:08",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494674108_IMG_4126.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "43",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-13 16:24:30",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494672870_IMG_4123.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "42",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-13 16:23:25",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494672805_IMG_4124.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "41",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-13 15:48:39",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494670719_IMG_4121.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "40",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-12 22:53:24",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494609804_IMG_4119.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "39",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-12 18:28:28",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494593908_IMG_4015.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "38",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-12 14:13:20",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494578600_IMG_4113.PNG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "37",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-12 14:13:18",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494578598_IMG_4113.PNG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "36",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-12 14:13:15",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494578595_IMG_4113.PNG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "35",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-12 14:13:12",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494578592_IMG_4113.PNG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "34",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-12 14:13:09",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494578589_IMG_4113.PNG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "33",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-11 23:43:42",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494526422_IMG_3950.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "32",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-11 23:43:10",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494526390_IMG_3944.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "31",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-11 23:26:24",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494525384_IMG_3127.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "30",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-11 23:26:20",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494525380_IMG_3127.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "29",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-11 23:24:12",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494525252_IMG_2600.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "28",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-11 23:24:06",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494525246_IMG_2600.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "27",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-11 23:22:04",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494525124_IMG_3113.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "26",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-11 23:21:11",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494525071_1491304854804.jpeg",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "25",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-11 23:20:26",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494525026_IMG_4050.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "24",
        "post_desc": "Ganesh Mahotsav 2016 ",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-11 23:20:01",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494525001_IMG_4045.PNG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "23",
        "post_desc": "",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-11 23:19:03",
        "files": [{
            "file_name": "1494524943_IMG_4016.JPG",
            "file_type": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "post_id": "22",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude0d\n",
        "firstname": "karan",
        "lastname": "qq",
        "created_at": "2017-05-10 14:57:16",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "21",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude0a\n",
        "firstname": "karan",
        "lastname": "qq",
        "created_at": "2017-05-04 11:06:07",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "20",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude0a\n",
        "firstname": "karan",
        "lastname": "qq",
        "created_at": "2017-05-04 11:06:03",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "19",
        "post_desc": "Good morning",
        "firstname": "karan",
        "lastname": "qq",
        "created_at": "2017-05-04 11:05:27",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "18",
        "post_desc": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Qtp42J9IOUo",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:39:53",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "17",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude1c",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:38:40",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "16",
        "post_desc": "hi hello",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:30:35",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "15",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude0e\ud83d\ude34\ud83d\ude01",
        "firstname": "Manish",
        "lastname": "Amin",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:30:19",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "14",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude0e\ud83d\ude34\ud83d\ude01",
        "firstname": "Manish",
        "lastname": "Amin",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:30:17",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "13",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude0e\ud83d\ude34\ud83d\ude01",
        "firstname": "Manish",
        "lastname": "Amin",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:30:17",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "12",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude0e\ud83d\ude34\ud83d\ude01",
        "firstname": "Manish",
        "lastname": "Amin",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:30:16",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "11",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude0e\ud83d\ude34\ud83d\ude01",
        "firstname": "Manish",
        "lastname": "Amin",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:30:16",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "10",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude04\u263a\ufe0f\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude01",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:30:14",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "9",
        "post_desc": "Going to receive loads of money....",
        "firstname": "Manish",
        "lastname": "Amin",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:08:58",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "8",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:08:57",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "7",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:08:55",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "6",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02",
        "firstname": "Abc",
        "lastname": "Xyz",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:08:47",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "5",
        "post_desc": "\ud83c\udfe1\ud83c\udfeb",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:05:40",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "4",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\udc4d\ud83d\udc4d\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude12\ud83d\udc2e\ud83d\ude48\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude09\ud83d\ude03",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 16:02:21",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "3",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude12\ud83d\ude0a",
        "firstname": "Rushin",
        "lastname": "Patel",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 15:58:42",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "2",
        "post_desc": "\ud83d\ude33\ud83d\ude33\ud83d\ude33",
        "firstname": "jaxi",
        "lastname": "chawda",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 15:57:31",
        "files": []
    }, {
        "post_id": "1",
        "post_desc": "hii....good afternoon...\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude04",
        "firstname": "jaxi",
        "lastname": "chawda",
        "created_at": "2017-05-02 15:55:49",
        "files": []
    }]
}
```

Here is my Android code:

```
   String filename = "";
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");
                if(posts != null && posts.length() > 0 ) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject fileObj = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String fName = fileObj.getString("firstname");
                        String created_at = fileObj.getString("created_at");
                        String post_desc = fileObj.getString("post_desc");


                        Log.e("Details", fName + "" + created_at + "" + post_desc);

                        JSONArray files = fileObj.getJSONArray("files");
                        if(files != null && files.length() > 0 ) {

                            for (int j = 0; j < files.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject Jsonfilename = files.getJSONObject(j);
                                filename = Jsonfilename.getString("file_name");
                                filename = "www.sample.com/home_webservice/compress/"+filename;
                                Log.e("Files", "" + filename);
                            }
                        }

                        Data_SAerver item = new Data_SAerver(fName,created_at,post_desc,filename);
                        data_sAervers.add(item);
                    }
                }

          adapter = new MyAdapter(data_sAervers,getApplicationContext());

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

DATA SERVER CLASS CODE

```
public class Data_SAerver {

    private String firstname;
    private  String created_at;
    private  String post_desc;


    private String filepath; /*= "http://cleanvadodara.esy.es/images/";*/

    public Data_SAerver(String firstname, String created_at, String post_desc,String filepath)
    { this.firstname = firstname;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.post_desc = post_desc;
        this.filepath = filepath;
    }
    public String getfilepath()
    { return filepath; }

    public Data_SAerver(String firstname, String created_at, String post_desc) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.post_desc = post_desc;

    }


    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public String getPost_desc() {
        return post_desc;
    }


}
```

MY ADAPTER CLASS

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Data_SAerver> data_sAervers;

    private Context context;
    public MyAdapter(List<Data_SAerver> data_sAervers, Context context) {
        this.data_sAervers = data_sAervers;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sample, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Data_SAerver data_sAerver = data_sAervers.get(position);
        holder.firstname.setText(data_sAerver.getFirstname());
        holder.created_at.setText(data_sAerver.getCreated_at());
        holder.post_desc.setText(data_sAerver.getPost_desc());
        Picasso.with(context).load(data_sAerver.getfilepath()).resize(736,1128).onlyScaleDown().into(holder.files);
   }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data_sAervers.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView firstname;
        public TextView created_at;
        public  TextView post_desc;
        public ImageView files;
        boolean isImageFitToScreen;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            firstname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
            created_at = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.created_at);
            post_desc= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            files = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_files);


         //   ImageViewPopUpHelper.enablePopUpOnClick(ViewHolder.this, files);

           /* files.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(isImageFitToScreen) {
                        isImageFitToScreen=true;
                        files.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        files.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    }else{
                        isImageFitToScreen=false;
                        files.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        files.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    }
                }
            });*/

        }
    }

}
```

Please help to solve this error. Thank you.

Comment: add the error report. so that its easy to help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The code that you sent is simple JSON parsing. Please send your error log and the code where you are getting this error.

Comment: actully i m getting same image for all user so i only want those who post image useing POST_ID   @Target

Comment: Before going to get directly from that file_name. First check that json has the param like this. Jsonfilename.has("file_name");. If it is there then read that 'file_name' is empty or not for that specific position and use it.

Comment: I m new in this area  so please help me explain with example @Rameshbabu

Comment: anyone please help to  play video using filepath from json @Rameshbabu

Comment: Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.viedo_name);
        videoHolder.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoHolder.start();

Comment: i want play video from json file which has only filename u can see above json code and android code @Rameshbabu

Comment: can u help me @Rameshbabu

Answer (score 1):

Your Android Code

```
String filename = "";
  String filetype = "";
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");
                if(posts != null && posts.length() > 0 ) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject fileObj = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String fName = fileObj.getString("firstname");
                        String created_at = fileObj.getString("created_at");
                        String post_desc = fileObj.getString("post_desc");


                        Log.e("Details", fName + "" + created_at + "" + post_desc);

                        JSONArray files = fileObj.getJSONArray("files");
                        if(files != null && files.length() > 0 ) 
                        {

                            for (int j = 0; j < files.length(); j++) 
                            {
                                JSONObject Jsonfilename = files.getJSONObject(j);
                                filename = Jsonfilename.getString("file_name");
                                filetype=jsonfilename.getString("file_type")
                                filename = "http://uat.ziplife.in/img/Post/compress/"+filename;
                                Log.e("Files", "" + filename);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            filname="";
                            filetype="";
                        }

                        Data_SAerver item = new Data_SAerver(fName,created_at,post_desc,filename,file_type);
                        data_sAervers.add(item);
                    }
                }

          adapter = new MyAdapter(data_sAervers,getApplicationContext());

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

Your Model

```
public class Data_SAerver {

    private String firstname;
    private  String created_at;
    private  String post_desc;


    private String filepath; 
    private String filetype;/*= "http://cleanvadodara.esy.es/images/";*/

    public Data_SAerver(String firstname, String created_at, String post_desc,String filepath,String filetype)
    { this.firstname = firstname;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.post_desc = post_desc;
        this.filepath = filepath;
        this.filetype = filetype;
    }
    public String getfilepath()
    { return filepath; }

    public Data_SAerver(String firstname, String created_at, String post_desc) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.post_desc = post_desc;

    }


    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public String getPost_desc() {
        return post_desc;
    }
    public String getFiletype() {
        return filetype;
    }



}
```

Your My Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Data_SAerver> data_sAervers;

    private Context context;
    public MyAdapter(List<Data_SAerver> data_sAervers, Context context) {
        this.data_sAervers = data_sAervers;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sample, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v,context);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
     {

        Data_SAerver data_sAerver = data_sAervers.get(position);
        holder.firstname.setText(data_sAerver.getFirstname());
        holder.created_at.setText(data_sAerver.getCreated_at());
        holder.post_desc.setText(data_sAerver.getPost_desc());

        holder.filepathurl.setText(data_sAerver.getfilepath());
        if(data_sAerver.getFiletype().equals("1"))
        {
            holder.files.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(context).load(data_sAerver.getfilepath()).resize(736,1128).onlyScaleDown().into(holder.files);
            holder.playvideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            if(data_sAerver.getFiletype().equals("2"))
            {
                holder.playvideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.files.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
   }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data_sAervers.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        public TextView firstname;
        public TextView created_at;
        public  TextView post_desc;
        public ImageView files;
        boolean isImageFitToScreen;
        public TextView filepathurl;
        Public Textview playvideo;
        Context con;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView,Context context) 
        {
            super(itemView);
            filepathurl = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.filepathurl);
            filepathurl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            playvideo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.playvideo);
            firstname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
            created_at = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.created_at);
            post_desc= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            files = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_files);
            con=context;

         //   ImageViewPopUpHelper.enablePopUpOnClick(ViewHolder.this, files);

           /* files.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(isImageFitToScreen) {
                        isImageFitToScreen=true;
                        files.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        files.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    }else{
                        isImageFitToScreen=false;
                        files.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        files.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    }
                }
            });*/
           playvideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                   Intent play=new Intent(con,PLayVideo.java);
                   play.putExtra("url",filepathurl.getText().toString());
                   startActivity(play);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In your sample xml add two more fields one filepathurl Textview, second add one more TextView with text Playvideo and setvisibility to Gone and set the visibility of files ImageView to gone.

Your PlayVideo Activity

```
  public class PlayVideo extends Activity
    {

        // Declare variables
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        VideoView videoview;


        String VideoURL = "";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Get the layout from video_main.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.video_main);

            VideoURL=getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
            // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
            videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
            // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask

            // Create a progressbar
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlayVideo.this);
            // Set progressbar title
            pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
            // Set progressbar message
            pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            // Show progressbar
            pDialog.show();

            try
            {
                // Start the MediaController
                MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                        PlayVideo.this);
                mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
                // Get the URL from String VideoURL
                Log.i("VideoURL",""+VideoURL);
                Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
                videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
                videoview.setVideoURI(video);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            videoview.requestFocus();
            videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                // Close the progress bar and play the video
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    videoview.start();
                }
            });

        }

}
```

Your VideoView xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147652/discussion-on-answer-by-magenative-how-to-get-values-from-a-particular-id-using).

Answer (score 0):

This is my activity code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iconone"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/firstname"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:text="Karan Brahmaxatriya"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#2196fe" />


                    <TextView

                        android:id="@+id/created_at"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:text="23/05/2017  6:05 PM"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#333333"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_files"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                 />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/filepathurl"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="filepathurl"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/playvideo"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="playvideo"/>
          <VideoView
              android:id="@+id/videoView"
              android:visibility="gone"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="190dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="ccvvzv"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#333333" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/comment_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Comment" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/repost_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Repost" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/like_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Like" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```